# Uboot: How to automatically load kernel image onto raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, u-boot

I am trying to load a new kernel image onto my raspberry pi. I've got u-boot-2018-11 and trying to have the kernel load automatically with uEnv.txt but there is not change in the out put with or without the text file. I have also tried boot.scr and boot.scr.uimg but nothing seems to work. I don't know for sure what to put into those files but uboot doesn't even recognize them.

For the uEnv.txt I put...

uenvcmd=fatload mmc 0:6 0x08000000 kernel8.img; fatload mmc 0:6 0x09000000 rpi-3b-plus.dtb;bootm 0x08000000 - 0x09000000;

Answer (score 0):

So the u-boot I am using doesn't recognize uEnv.txt and I wasn't putting the correct stuff in the other two things. What I ended up doing was..

setenv bootcmd 'fatload mmc 0:6 0x08000000 kernel8.img; fatload mmc 0:6 0x09000000 rpi-3b-plus.dtb;bootm 0x08000000 - 0x09000000;'
saveenv

and that works